# tensorflow error : 'ConfigProto' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, tensorflow

i'm using tensorflow to do some training. Actually it does well but when I wanna save `.ckpt`, the error shows. I tried many version of tensorflow like `0.11`, `0.12`, `1.0`, `1.3` nearly all of them. But the error is still there. I didn't give `ConfigProto` object a name and I really don't know what happens.

The code is here.

```
config=tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
config.allow_soft_placement=True
saver=tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess
...
saver.save(sess,'%s/'%dumpdir+keyname+".ckpt")
```

If I annotate the last line, it won't go wrong but it won't have a result either.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: just in the title.

Comment: I have the same error. Do you find a solution?